# null on HTTPPost on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, null, http-post

My Problem is like this ,Im trying to get a model object from a view after seinding it with a form,the model Looks like this:

```
public class PackageModel
{
    public PackageDTO Package { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Allcategories { get; set; }

}
```

while PackageDTO is just an DTO object conatining many attributes.
Now the view for this model,ist just showing the attributes and this model will be sent within a httppost request to the index page as normal(there it will be processed ans saved ),
the index method in the Controller Looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(PackagemODEL packageModel, FormCollection form)
    {

    }
```

Now i dont know what im doing wrong,but the Object packageModel is not totally null,just  the list Allcategories  and another string Attribute in the PackageDTO object,the rest seems to be working.

The view contains this code

```
<fieldset>
<legend>@Resources.AppvManagementService_EditPackage_Title</legend>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","WantedController",FormMethod.Post,new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <labelName </label>@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Package.Name) <br/>
    <label>Sid </label>@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Package.Sid,new {@disabled="disabled"}) <br/>
    <label>Category </label>@Html.DropDownList("CategoryName",Model.Allcategories,Model.Package.Category)<br/>

    <label>Description: </label>@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Package.Description) <br/>


    <label>Type: </label>@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Package.Type) <br/>

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
}
```

Doest anyone have any idea why ist like this?? am i doing something wrong(im sure i am :))

thx for every one

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect `Allcategories` to be populated? Your view contains a field, which posts a value under the name `"CategoryName"` - there's nothing in your view that populates a list of categories. More importantly; to you really *need* it to be populated? It seems to me that `Allcategories` is only really needed for populating the dropdown in the view. On the post, you shouldn't need it. If you DO still need it, you're going to have to either:

Repopulate it in the controller on the `HttpPost` method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PackagemODEL packageModel, FormCollection form)
{
    packageModel.Allcategories = new IEnumerable<SelectListItem>();
}
```

Clutter up your view with pointless hidden fields to pass the values back in (I wouldn't recommend this for a list of items unless you really need to):

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Allcategories.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.Allcategories[i])
}
```

Populate it in the model constructor:

```
public class PackageModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Allcategories { get; set; }

    public PackageModel()
    {
       Allcategories = new IEnumerable<SelectListItem>();
       /* Add values  to Allcategories here */
    }
}
```

If the values of `Allcategories` doesn't change, you could also consider making it a `static readonly` property of your model and hardcoding the values (or pulling them from a config file or similar).

As for getting back the selected CategoryName, you need a field in your model in which to store it, otherwise the only way to access it at the moment is via `Request.Form`:

```
public class PackageModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Allcategories { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryName, Model.Allcategories, Model.Package.Category)
```

**An aside:** Please, please, *please* take your DTO out of your model and set appropriate properties in your model itself. Your DTO *does not belong* in your view model, which is a *model for your view* and nothing more.

Comment: I've tried it with
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.CategoryName,Model.Allcategories, Model.Package.Category)
but still i am geting  Zero elements in the list (but not null),
And if i do something like this how could i find wich object did i picked from the list because in the posted model i still having the old one
i getting over this Problem with having hidden attributes in the view but i thought it could be better done and why dou you think i Need to take the DTOout of my model?i thought it would be better than copying the same code again
i wanted to extend the model class,do you think ist good?

Comment: Im sorry i couldnt pack every Thing I wanted to say in one post,but I hope I have expressed myself well,and thx :)

Comment: I think you need to reread my answer with a bit more care. You get the selected value from the `CategoryName` property that I added and - if you need to get the list of values back in the POST (which I'm not sure you do) - you need to implement one of the options I described above. A DropDownList doesn't give you the list values back, only the selected item.

Comment: Finally, you need to take your DTO out of your model because your DTO is concerned with data access and your view has nothing to do with data access. Create a model to contain just the fields your view needs and populate the DTO in your controller (or, better yet, in a separate, abstracted application layer). That's the whole point of a view model.